# Python XPath : Is it possible to have optional XPath query?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

i have the following way of parsing an xml

```
import re
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

inString = """
<doc>

<q></q>

<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>1</p3>
        <p3>2</p3>
        <p3>32</p3>
        <p3>3</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>4</p3>
        <p3>5</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>6</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
<r></r>
<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>7</p3>
        <p3>8</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>9</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>10</p3>
        <p3>11</p3>
        <p3>XYZ</p3>
        <p3>12</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
</doc>
"""
root = fromstring(inString)

#nodes = root.xpath("./doc//p1/p2/p3[contains(text(),'ABC') or contains(text(),'XYZ')]/preceding-sibling::p3")

ns = {"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}
nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3", namespaces=ns)
```

which gives me

```
4 5 7 8 10 11
```

so it completely skips the first `<p2>` my ideal output is

```
1 2 32 3 4 5 7 8 10 11
```

so, if i cant find a `<p3>ABC<p3>` or `<p3>XYZ<p3>` in a `<p2>`, i still want all the `<p3>` s of that `<p2>`. is that possible?

**EDIT**

i tried

```
".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p3"
```

but that gives me

```
1 2 32 3 4 5 ABC 6 7 8 ABC 9 10 11 XYZ 12
```

which is everything

**Partial Solution**

i tried the following xpath

```
".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p3[not (contains(text(),'ABC') or contains(text(),'XYZ'))]/preceding-sibling::p3"
```

which gives me

```
1 2 32 4 5 ABC 7 8 ABC 10 11 XYZ
```

which is better but still incorrect. note that it is missing `6` and it includes the `ABC` and `XYZ` which i did not want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start, how about:

```
.//p3[text() = 'XYZ' or text() = 'ABC']/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p2[not(p3[text() = 'ABC' or text() = 'XYZ'])]/p3
```

That is: for each p2 which has no p3 children equal to ABC or XYZ, give me the p3 children.

(string equals instead of regexp, because regexps are not needed in this example, but you could use regexp instead)

Comment: but it does not work with re:match. i tried nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p2[not(re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')])]/p3", namespaces=ns) but it gives me error

Comment: There is a syntax error, you are missing 'p3[' after 'not(' (count the parenthesis)

Comment: you mean ".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p2[not(p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]])]/p3"? i still get the error. however this works ".//p3[re:match(.,'XYZ') or re:match(.,'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3 | .//p2[not(p3[text() = 'ABC' or text() = 'XYZ'])]/p3"

Comment: wait i fixed it. you were right. thanks a lot for your help :)